# Matching headers to table in XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to create a table using XSLT-XML styling. The issue I am having is trying to place headers on the information contained in my table.

```
<xsl:template match="team/player">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@checkname"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@min"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@fgm"/> - <xsl:value-of select="stats/@fga"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@fgm3"/> - <xsl:value-of select="stats/@fga3"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@ftm"/> - <xsl:value-of select="stats/@fta"/></td>      
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@oreb"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@dreb"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@treb"/></td>   
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@ast"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@stl"/></td>    
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@blk"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@to"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="stats/@pf"/></td>             
            </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the template I am using to apply templates. Whenever I try adding headers into this template it will repeat them each time for every entry. There are 10 players I am pulling these stats/values from. I attempted to do this...

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>PLAYERS</th>
    <th>MIN</th>
    <th>FGM-A</th>
    <th>3PM-A</th>
    <th>FTM-A</th>
    <th>OREB</th>
    <th>DREB</th>
    <th>REB</th>
    <th>AST</th>
    <th>STL</th>
    <th>BLK</th>
    <th>TO</th>
    <th>PF</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="team[@vh='H']/player"/>
</tr>
</table>
```

But my columns were not lined up with the data in the template. Is there anyway to do this where I can match up headers such as Players, Mins, Ast, etc. to their corresponding values in the the template.

Comment: I opted not to include the XML as it is quite long and all my data is being displayed properly. It's just not lining up the way I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the "lining up" issue is caused by you adding a table within your table.

To fix that you can remove the `<tr>` from around your `apply-templates` call and then update your `template` to remove the `<table>`. That should create a single table and line up your elements correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have been busy at work. My code is working now. Thanks so much for your help.